# MudBlazor: how to switch Dark/Light theme?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I try to use it for Dark/Light theme switch . The question is: I have made it on one page, it works, but how to do : I add switch to the component Settings.razor and the selected theme is using for all pages and after restart too? Now it works on one page only. The code as in the doc

```
<MudThemeProvider @bind-IsDarkMode="@_isDarkMode" Theme="_theme" />

<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="@_isDarkMode" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ma-4" T="bool" Label="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" />
@code { private bool _isDarkMode;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the theme classes into your main layout class:

#### MainLayout.razor

```cs
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<app>
  <MudThemeProvider Theme="@this.currentTheme"/>
  <MudDialogProvider />
  <MudSnackbarProvider />

  <MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="0">
      <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@this.DrawerToggle"/>
      <MudSpacer/>
      @if (this.darkModeActive)
      {
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.LightMode" OnClick="@this.ToggleDarkMode" Title="To light mode"/>
      }
      else
      {
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.DarkMode" OnClick="@this.ToggleDarkMode" Title="To dark mode"/>
      }
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@this.drawerOpen" Elevation="1">
      <MudNavMenu>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="px-4">Demo</MudText>
        <MudDivider Class="my-2"/>
        <MudNavLink Href="/">Home</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/page-1">Page 1</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/page-2">Page 2</MudNavLink>
      </MudNavMenu>
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
      <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Large" Class="my-16 pt-16">
        @Body
      </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
  </MudLayout>

  @code {
    private static readonly MudTheme defaultTheme = new();

    private static readonly MudTheme darkTheme = new()
    {
      Palette = new Palette
      {
        Black = "#27272f",
        Background = "#32333d",
        BackgroundGrey = "#27272f",
        Surface = "#373740",
        DrawerBackground = "#27272f",
        DrawerText = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.50)",
        DrawerIcon = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.50)",
        AppbarBackground = "#27272f",
        AppbarText = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.70)",
        TextPrimary = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.70)",
        TextSecondary = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.50)",
        ActionDefault = "#adadb1",
        ActionDisabled = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.26)",
        ActionDisabledBackground = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.12)",
        Divider = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.12)",
        DividerLight = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.06)",
        TableLines = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.12)",
        LinesDefault = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.12)",
        LinesInputs = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.3)",
        TextDisabled = "rgba(255,255,255, 0.2)",
        TableStriped = "#3f3f45"
      }
    };

    private bool darkModeActive = false;
    private bool drawerOpen = true;
    private MudTheme currentTheme = defaultTheme;

    void DrawerToggle()
    {
      this.drawerOpen = !this.drawerOpen;
    }

    void ToggleDarkMode()
    {
      this.darkModeActive = !this.darkModeActive;
      this.currentTheme = this.darkModeActive ? darkTheme : defaultTheme;
    }
  }
</app>
```

#### Index.razor

```cs
@page "/"

<MudText>Index</MudText>
```

#### Page1.razor

```cs
@page "/page-1"

<MudText>Page 1</MudText>
```

#### Page2.razor

```cs
@page "/page-2"

<MudText>Page 2</MudText>
```

#### App.razor

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: Great, will try. One question: is selected theme kept between App restarts?

Comment: @ZedZip no, since Blazor is a SPA framework, the `darkModeActive` will be reset not only after a restart of the app, but also when you refresh the page with F5. If you want to persist such things, store it in your browser's local storage.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#browser-storage-server

Comment: For `private static readonly MudTheme darkTheme = new()` you can use `PaletteDark = new PaletteDark()` this adds the default darktheme so you do not have to define all default colors.

Comment: @Taco ah, that is a new class I guess. But that seems to be a `Palette` and not a `MudTheme` (which is what a `MudThemeProvider` needs), so I one cannot simply replace `MudTheme darkTheme = new()` with  a `PaletteDark`. Feel free to provide a new answer, of course!

Comment: I would like a new answer on how to dynamically update the Palette.  It does not work to have two different pallets and just change the theme.

Answer (score 5):

MudBlazor have all things ready for Dark/Light theme.

Official documentation: https://mudblazor.com/customization/overview#dark-palette

> Dark palettes are integrated in `MudTheme`. Just set `IsDarkMode` to `true`.

```html
<MudThemeProvider @bind-IsDarkMode="@_isDarkMode" Theme="_theme"/>
<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="@_isDarkMode" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ma-4" T="bool" Label="Toggle Light/Dark Mode"/>

<MudText Class="ma-4">This is an example text!</MudText>
@code{
    private MudTheme _theme = new();
    private bool _isDarkMode;
}
```

Try it: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYmHOmPHzNQggwbr

You can even customize your theme:
https://mudblazor.com/customization/overview#custom-themes

Comment: Ah, nice! Last time I checked, you had to roll your own theme. Much better like this.